# How to Block user from sending messages in telegram group using python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

is there any way to block users from sending messages till they do what Admin says.
At all I want to code a bot for my telegram group with python which is going to block users till they send an introduction voice, and they should wait till admins accept their request to join the group. Is there anyway?

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`client.edit_permissions`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.edit_permissions) to edit the permissions of a user in a group. Preventing someone from talking is as simple as doing the following:

```py
await client.edit_permissions(chat, user, send_messages=False)
```

This will prevent `user` from sending messages in `chat` until an administrator changes their permissions back (or through code, with `send_messages=True`).

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your issue, in that case.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot.